# JavaScript, constructor and "this"

Tags: javascript, this, ecmascript-5

There's something I don't understand with "this" keyword, more precisely when there is no "this". like this example :

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name=name;
    this.go = function() {
        console.log("My name is " + name);
    }
}

let person = new Person("Peter");
person.go();
```

My problem is when I call go() on person object. Why does it work ?? I thought I needed to put "this.name" inside my method.
Because when I run person.go(), inside the go() method : name is not a parameter, is not a local variable and not a global variable either.
How the JS engine manages to understand what "name" means ?

For example when I do that :

```
var person = {
   name: "Peter",
   go: function() {console.log("My name is " + name);}
};
```

person.go() doesn't work because "name" is unknown and I have to add this.name to make it work.

I don't understand why it works in the first example but not the second one.

Thanks

Comment: "name is [...] not a local variable" - Yes, it is.

Comment: Think of any variables defined outside of a function as globals for any inner functions (within the same {}), and this as a reference to a object (that happens to be a function)

Comment: FYI `name` is not a good identifier to use in client-side code as `name` is also a Global property of the `window` object and can cause bugs later on in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works without `this.` because the `go` function has captured the `name` parameter from the constructor function in the surrounding scope.  Your code is equivalent to:

```
function Person(xyz) {
    this.name=xyz;
    this.go = function() {
        console.log("My name is " + xyz);
    }
}
```

IE you're not actually making use of the `name` property of your `Person` object.

Comment: OK, so does that mean the go() function is a closure ?

Comment: @AntonBoarf Yes.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the `name` value comes from the function argument `name`. The `go` method uses the argument's value, instead of the `this` context.

In the second case, `name` is undefined in the `go` method. You need to provide a context (`this.name`) in order to access it.